# Help with verbatim-like environments

Tags: verbatim, parsing

I am writing a script for LaTeX shallow parsing (assuming that there are no complicated definitions in the preamble). First of all I decided to check
the document for in-line verbatims and comments, because they make TeX meta characters inactive. I have managed to parse document into three different types:
`inlineVerbatim`, `inlineComment` and `Other`. However I am still wondering, are there any other in-line commands, that make any of the metacharacters `{}\#^_$&%~` inactive or force to have different syntax meaning? Also it would be a big help if someone told me about enviroments with the same properties besides 
`verbatim`,`comment` and `listling`.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of your script?  If you can explain a bit more, that might help.  One thing you may want to scan for is `\string`.

Comment: in the base latex format there are `\verb` `verbatim` `verbatim*` and to some extent `\index`. But you also mention `comment` and `listing` which are from contributed packages. If you include arbitrary packages the list is endless, the commands of `fancyvrb` for example

Comment: I am working with other people TeX files, so I am trying to write simple script that tries to parse document with most commonly used LaTeX commands and packages. My first goal would be to create dvi file, delete all comments, generate another dvi and compare source code. If they are identical, continue working with clean source. Another goal would be ability to check some patterns in different environments. I understand that full analysis is impossible, because TeX is quite complicated language. In advance knowing some packages and commands that changes usual syntax would be helpful.